# Infinite loop cant figure out how to stop it java

Tags: java, for-loop

Hi, I'm trying to learn Java slowly, but I'm having trouble with a infinite loop. Below is my code. From the start of the constructor until the end of the display method, how do I go about making the loop stop after the last entry added?

```
public UnitResults(int Size, String title)
{            
    this.fName = new String [Size];
    this.surname = new String [Size];
    this.Marks = new int [Size];
    pointer = 0;

    fName[pointer] = "Daniel";
    surname[pointer] = "Scullion";

    Marks[pointer] = 60;
    unitTitle  = title;

    pointer ++;

}

public Boolean add( String tempfName, String tempsName, int newGrade)
{ 
    if (pointer == fName.length)
    {
    System.out.println("The Students Database is full");
    return false;
    }
    else
    { 
        fName [pointer] = tempfName;
        surname [pointer]  = tempsName;
        Marks[pointer] = newGrade;
        pointer ++;
        System.out.println("Student Added");
        return true;
    }
} // end Add

public void display()
{
    System.out.println("Students Results\n");
    for (int index = 0; index < pointer; index++)
    {
        System.out.println( unitTitle + "\n" 
            + fName[index] + "\n"  
            + surname[index] + "\n" 
            + Marks[index] + "\n"
            + "\n" );  
        index++;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: I can't see an infinite loop. But beware of the following: having `index++;` also inside the loop, will make you skip every second entry.

Comment: I would step through your program in your debugger so you understand what each line of code does.  There is many lines of code which doesn't appear to be there for a good reason and when you debug your program you could learn something.

Comment: oh dear i am an idiot.. in my menu system it just keep looping the display method it was nothing to do with it atall.. sorry for wasting your time! thanks for looking at it!

Comment: Please either delete the question or post your answer and mark it as solved. This will help people not waste time trying to answer the question.

Comment: Notice that it is also a good thing to start each variable (field or local variable) with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index++; line is not required and indeed is probably the cause of your infinite loop. The index++ is already specified in the for() statement. Adding is again means that index is incremented by 2 for each loop.

```
for (int index=0; index < pointer;  index ++)
{

    System.out.println( unitTitle + "\n" 
            + fName[index] + "\n"  
            + surname[index] + "\n" 
            + Marks[index] + "\n"
            + "\n" );  
    index++; // <<<----- this line should not be here

}
```

Comment: I don't see how index++; would create an infinite loop (please specify), but you are correct.

Comment: See comment under post ;) But it can't be the reason for an infinite loop!

Comment: in the menu system i did not declare the option to go back to the menu system so it was looping the method forever

Comment: in the menu system i did not declare the option to go back to the menu system so it was looping the method forever. it
dosent let me answer my own question just yet so il just tick this